# How to resolve templated-types from instances in C++

Tags: c++, templates, types, template-meta-programming

When I look into the GNU implementation of the STL chrono library, I see:

```cpp
    /// seconds
    typedef duration<int64_t>           seconds;
```

I would like to decode the `int64_t` *(specifically the type, not the value)* from the `duration` type for further static evaluation.

Is there a way to perform template meta programming to achieve this?

> ***EDIT:** I'm not interested in the value of the duration, I only care to know the type used to represent it.*

Comment: What do you mean by "decode"?

Comment: You probably want [rep](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration#Member_types).

Comment: `std::chrono::milliseconds mils = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(sec)` ???

Comment: I was unaware of `rep`, it looks like they be what I'm looking for. Can it be tested statically?

Comment: I'm not interested in the value of the duration, only the type used to represent that value. I will make an edit to the post.

Comment: C++ is statically typed, so yes.

Comment: i.e. `std::is_integral< std::chrono::seconds::rep >` ?

Comment: @VictorGubin I need to know the type _(not its traits)_, but your example succintly illustrates similar behavior as that I'm wishing to achieve. If you will supply this as an answer, I will give you the checkmark.

Comment: I have attempted to ask a straight-forward question. If you are going to down vote, please leave a comment so I can clarify the post.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
template<class T> struct HeadArg;
template<template<class...> class Ctor, class H, class... More>
struct HeadArg<Ctor<H, More...>> {
    using type = H;
};
```

Comment: `std::chrono::duration` has a member type `rep`. You don't need to resort to template specialization tricks.

Comment: Unfortunately, the question title is a bit broader than that.